# Decode a binary value in Python which will give the same output as Postgres decode

Tags: python, bytea

I have to decode value `'9DAFF2834DDD73C18D79E31DE22F0D49DF13E525D3FFAE599530BECCD1B916FF'` to hex in python:

For this I am doing

```
>>> import binascii
>>>
>>> binascii.unhexlify('9DAFF2834DDD73C18D79E31DE22F0D49DF13E525D3FFAE599530BECCD1B916FF')
>>>'\x9d\xaf\xf2\x83M\xdds\xc1\x8dy\xe3\x1d\xe2/\rI\xdf\x13\xe5%\xd3\xff\xaeY\x950\xbe\xcc\xd1\xb9\x16\xff'
```

But, postgres is giving value as:

```
>>> db=> select decode('9DAFF2834DDD73C18D79E31DE22F0D49DF13E525D3FFAE599530BECCD1B916FF','hex') as sha;
```

The output is:

```
>>> \235\257\362\203M\335s\301\215y\343\035\342/\015I\337\023\345%\323\377\256Y\2250\276\314\321\271\026\377
```

Is there any equivalent in Python which will give same result as in Postgres (the Postgres output is a bytea)?

Answer (score 1):

Not to be rude, but they're exactly the same. One is octal, the other hexadecimal.

```
>>> '\235\257\362\203M\335s\301\215y\343\035\342/\015I\337\023\345%\323\377\256Y\2250\276\314\321\271\026\377'
'\x9d\xaf\xf2\x83M\xdds\xc1\x8dy\xe3\x1d\xe2/\rI\xdf\x13\xe5%\xd3\xff\xaeY\x950\xbe\xcc\xd1\xb9\x16\xff'
```